# Weblogic 10.3 Session Not timeout

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

I did upgrade Weblogic from version6 to version 10. Weblogic is configured replicated_if_cluster with 2 servers, and using "multicast" for communications  between clusters. But Sessions never times out, even though I set Max Inactive Interval of Session session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300)

It worked before I did upgrade version, and it's working on a single server (not cluster).
Please advise!

Comment: How do you know that the sessions are not timing out? Have the WebLogic Server logs confirmed this fact? It might so happen that the application is written in a manner that will prevent session timeouts.

Comment: I tested session timeout by opening a new browser window (login), and waiting for 5-10 minutes, but it didn't. No application is preventing session timeout. It works on local server (single server), but not work on the production server (have clusters replicated, and using iPlanet load balancing)

Comment: It might help if you can use the [DebugHttp logger of WebLogic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webapp/configureservlet.html#wp158520). It might give you an idea of the expiration time of the session. Also, you can track sessions from the Admin Console, if you can enable the [session-monitoring-flag](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1067857). I believe it would you in identifying the actual issue behind the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set the session time out intervals either in `web.xml` or `weblogic.xml`. This way it is guaranteed to work. Setting the `setMaxInactiveInterval` in the `Session` Object only invalidates the object inself.